# how to restore the data that has already been fetched in recyclerview from firebase in fragment recreation

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, onsaveinstancestate

I have retrieved the data from real time database in recycler view but after recreation of fragment, same data is being fetched again. I want to restore the data that has already been fetched and set it to the recycler view after fragment recreation.

Answer (score 0):

Recreation Meaning Destroy every thing and create it again
I Suppose You Want to Minimize The Number Of Calls To Server To Reduce Usage And Billing Cost

the easiest one is to enable Persistence to your database
[the documentation about that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)
And Modify Your Code To Make A Check If The data Exist in Cache and get it
If Not so get it from Server

This Easy But Not good When You Update the data regularly

so the solution I suggest is to create a repository Class with Singleton Pattern to make single instance

and make the server calls on it's constructor to fetch all data you need

this way you make one call to server every time the app opens but when i come for recreation you will use the data excites in repository

**Example**
I Will Assume That You Get A List Of Strings

```
      public class Repository {
            private static Repository instance = null;
            private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
            private List<String> strings;
        
            private Repository (){
                strings = {Make Server Call Here}
            }
        
            public static Repository getInstance(){
                if (instance == null){
                    synchronized (LOCK){
                        if (instance == null){
                            instance = new Subjects_Repository();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return instance;
            }
           public List<String> getStrings(){
              return strings;
    }
```

**NOTE:** getting data from firebase done on background thread so make sure to get data from server first before use method getStrings();